# What is a good location equivalence test for comparison of small and large samples?

Tags: t-test, sample-size, small-sample, kruskal-wallis-test, equivalence

I have two one-dimensional samples, one is small (like 2 values) and another of a larger size (several dozens). I want to estimate the probability that the two samples are drawn from different distributions.
What would be a good test for this task (one sample is small + significant difference in the number of values in samples)? Kruskal-Wallis, Welch-Satterthwaite t-test, or something else? Preferably, normality-independent, as it is not clear if the sample of 2 values is distributed normally.

Comment: A sample size of two is going to sap away your power to reject. // That probability is not quite what a p-value mean. Do you mean a p-value, or do you literally need the probability that the samples were drawn from the same distribution? // What is your goal with “equivalence” that you’ve tagged? It will help us if we understand your problem and goals in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I need a p-value. My ultimate goal is to conclude if the group 1 and 2 (represented by the two smaples) are the "same" or "different".

Comment: What kind of tolerance for difference do you allow without the distributions being “different” for practical purposes? If the answer is zero, then you’re done; unless you’re doing a computer simulation (and perhaps not even then) the distributions are at least a little different.

Comment: Say, p-value of 0.05 is a threshold

Comment: That is not a difference between distributions, and by having that small sample size and an underpowered study, you are rigging it to "pass" the hypothesis test. A difference between distributions would be something like "if their means are within a meter of each other, that's close enough...call them practically equivalent."

Comment: Could you clarify the rigging part?

Comment: If you want to declare equivalence because $p>0.05$, then you can rig your test to lack power by having small sample sizes.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to rig anything. I just want to report whatever I see with a note that these conclusions are not reliable and require further investigation.  My question here is not about which test will give reliable answer in this situation, no one will and there is not enough data. The question is which test are **not wrong** to use in such a situation.

Comment: Hypothesis testing answers a different question than the one you want to ask. Hypothesis testing does not give evidence in favor of the null hypothesis.

Comment: I didn't say they do... What I need is a type of location equivalence test that can be correctly applied to the samples described above. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Equivalence testing requires the investigator to declare an effect size (not a p-value) of interest, where a difference less than that effect size is considered equivalent. You appear not to have an effect size of interest.

Comment: I can reformulate then - I need to perform a hypothesis test on two samples with hypothesis H0 that the true location parameters of the populations are equal

Comment: That cannot show equivalence.

Comment: Anyway, that is what my original question is about